# Why could no one reach the southernmost tip of India?

Tags: india

The southernmost tip of India was almost always occupied by the regional kingdoms of the region like [Chola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chola_dynasty) [Chera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chera_dynasty) [Pandya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandya_dynasty) and so on. However, no Indian empire was able to conquer it from the north. May that be Maurya Mughal or the Gupta empire. Why is it so? Why couldn't empires which crossed Vindhya and Satpura beat through the Nilgiris?

Comment: Did any northern Indian empire really want to conquer the south?

Comment: They don't need to get right up to the southern tip to gain access to the sea. Did many northern Indian powers even tried to go all the way to the southern tip? One gets the impression that it wasn't on their radar.

Comment: Isn't this just a reflection of the size of the subcontinent and the general lack of long-term stability of any of the empires that arose?  It seems like there were even times where the largest empire there was based in the south.

Comment: Mauryas controlled a lanfd larger than the subcontinent and during the rule of strong rulers Indian empires did have quite a lot of stability.There doesn't seem to be any reason why a land that could be so easily overrun was not even attacked.

Comment: 1) If I am not mistaken, c.250 BC, the Pandya's and Chola's were both vassals of the Mauryan Empire, so technically, the Maurya's had suzerainty all the way to the southern tip. 2) c.1300 AD, the Delhi Sultanate did in fact reach the southern tip and ruled there for some time. 3) The (British) East India Company controlled the southern tip including Ceylon early in the 1800's, and held control for more than a hundred years.

Answer (score 3):

The terrain. Most of southern India is covered by the [Deccan Plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deccan_Plateau).

According to Wikipedia,

> "The plateau is located between two mountain ranges, the Western Ghats and the Eastern Ghats, each of which rises from its respective nearby coastal plain, and almost converge at the southern tip of India. It is separated from the Gangetic plain to the north by the Satpura and Vindhya Ranges, which form its northern boundary."

Perhaps the greatest barrier to the south is the [Nilgiris Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilgiri_Mountains)

> "The Nilgiris district is one of the 38 districts in the southern Indian state of Tamil Nadu. Nilgiri (English: Blue Mountains) is the name given to a range of mountains spread across the borders among the states of Tamil Nadu, Karnataka and Kerala. The Nilgiri Hills are part of a larger mountain chain known as the Western Ghats. Their highest point is the mountain of Doddabetta, height 2,637 m. The district is contained mainly within the Nilgiri Mountains range."